# Does `alignof(N) == sizeof(N)` where N is an integral type?

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment

Does `alignof(N) == sizeof(N)` where N is an integral type?

I'm asking for both C and C++, hope this isn't a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386946/whats-the-difference-between-sizeof-and-alignof

Comment: `alignof(N)` necessarily divides `sizeof(N)` evenly but they need not be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's machine-specific.  On a 32-bit machine, `alignof(int64_t)` could easily be 4.  Too, assumptions that are widespread now won't be for so very long.

Comment: On arduinos `alignof(int64_t)` is 1!

Answer (score 2):

In C not necessarily.  At least I can't find anything in the draft
C99 or draft C11 standard that would require them to be the same.  An implementation
could theoretically have padding bits in its integer types, and it's
easy to envision some machine architecture where the alignment requirement was smaller than the size.  Consider a 64 bit integer on a system that only needed four byte alignment.

Comment: Padding bits are irrelevant, they're included in both `sizeof` and `alignof`.

Comment: Yes, but I can envision an architecture where the padding bits weren't relevant to the alignment requirements but value bits were.