# sizeof vs _Alignof value

Tags: c, alignment

Is there ever a time when the `_Alignof` returns a different value that `sizeof`? For example, every one that I've tried yields the same value:

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", _Alignof(int), sizeof (int));
printf("%zu %zu\n", _Alignof(char), sizeof (char));
```

> 4 4 
> 1 1

Are these two values ever different (other than with an array)?

Comment: C++ duplicate: [What's the difference between sizeof and alignof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386946/whats-the-difference-between-sizeof-and-alignof)

Comment: Try it with a struct with a few differently-sized members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `struct foo { int i; char c};`, many C implementations produce eight for `sizeof(struct foo)` and four for `_Alignof(struct foo)` because `int` is four bytes big and has an alignment requirement of four bytes. This is because the structure must have four-byte alignment to satisfy the `int` alignment, and that requires adding three bytes of padding, so the structure size is four bytes for the `int`, one for the `char`, and three for the padding.

Another possibility is that `long double` is 16 bytes in size but only requires eight-byte alignment. It might be 16 bytes because that much data is needed for it, but the hardware might have only an eight-byte bus, so only eight-byte alignment is required to be able to efficiently load the parts of any object.

Similarly, any machine will generally have some strictest alignment require *x* bytes because its bus is *x* bytes wide or its processor has a largest general word size of *x*, so the hardware can only process things in chunks of *x* bytes at a time. Then any objects larger than *x* bytes must be made out of multiple words and implemented using multiple instructions. For such objects, there is no need for alignment stricter than *x* bytes. For example, an eight-byte integer might be made out of two four-byte words with four-byte alignment, or, on older machines, a four-byte integer might be made out of two-byte words with two-byte alignment.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these two values ever different (other than with an array)?

Example difference, most likely found with a large type.

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(_Complex long double), _Alignof(_Complex long double));
```

Output (implementation dependent)

```
32 16
```

Comment: Indeed, the size and alignment of a complex number **must** be different; C 2018 6.2.5 13 requires a `complex foo` have the same representation and alignment requirement as a `foo [2]`, so the alignment is at most `sizeof(foo)` (else element 1 could not be aligned if element 0 were aligned), but the size is twice that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting: not only different, but exactly 2x, as you say.

Comment: Not necessarily exactly two times the alignment; a `double` could be eight bytes with an alignment requirement of four bytes, so a `complex` double would be 16 with four.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Good point. At _least_ 2x then.

Answer (score 1):

For a primitive type, a typical example would be `long long int` on a 32-bit platform.  It's a 64-bit type, so 8 bytes, but made up of two 32-bit words that have to be loaded and stored individually, so there is no need for any greater alignment than 4 bytes.

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jbY7s6)

Answer (score 1):

Trivial case where they **always must** be different:

- `sizeof(char[N]) == N`
- `_Alignof(char[N]) == 1`.