# Restriction on pointer types in C++

Tags: c++

I was doing a programming exercise for C++ and I came through this question

> what on your system has restriction on pointer types char* , int* and
> void*? For example, may an int* have an odd value? Hint:alignment

I have nothing to show what I have done, I have trouble understanding the question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386946/whats-the-difference-between-sizeof-and-alignof .

Comment: Pedantically, the question is sort of misworded. There are no such restrictions on pointers types themselves. System-specific restrictions must be met for *certain operations* to be legal on typed pointers.

Comment: As Frank noted, the wording is confusing. E.g. alignment is a CPU limitation, not language limitation. Some CPUs, IIRC ARMv5 and earlier, required variables to be naturally aligned, so a 4 bytes int would have to be stored in an address divisible by 4, and int* would have the least two significant bits zero.

Comment: The wording is certainly confusing. Given `int A[10];`, both `A+1` and `A+2` are pointers, and logically one is odd. A common _binary_ representation may have the lower bit set to zero in both cases, but C++ does not prescribe a binary representation. It's entirely valid for a CPU to use pointers in the same way that C++ does, in which case the C++ implementation would implement `A+1` indeed as an increment by one.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you _can_ have odd `int` pointers on certain platforms (surprisingly common ones). It comes with a performance penalty, but it doesn’t crash the Matrix.

Comment: @MSalters `A+1` and `A+2` are `sizeof(int)` apart

Comment: @Caleth: Indeed, _in bytes_. There's no rule in C++ that says a CPU must implement an `int*` as a byte pointer, though. `A+1`  could be represented as `0x1F` and `A+2`  as `0x20`. However, on such a platform `(char*)(A+1)` could be `0x3E` - casts do not need to preserve binary representation. That's why you **can** cast `int*` to `char*` but not `int**`  to `char**`.

Comment: @MSalters or `sizeof(int)` might be 1

Answer (score 3):

Objects of a given type can only be stored in memory at addresses that are a multiple of their alignment.

Also,  a valid pointer contains the memory address of an object of its type.

By combining these two, we can say that a valid pointer must absolutely contain an address that is a multiple of the alignment of its matching type.

You can ask the compiler to give you the alignment of a type for its current target system by using the `alignof()` operator. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "pointers to float must contain a multiple of " << alignof(float) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an answer. It’s just an example showing that the question is way too open-ended. Is it referring to the alignment of data structures outlined by a language standard or perhaps to memory alignment requirements of a particular hardware platform?

Let me share a secret:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

using std::uint8_t;
using std::uint32_t;
using std::uint64_t;

int main() {
  const uint64_t something{0x1020304050607080};
  std::cout << std::hex;
  for (const uint32_t shift : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) {
    const uint32_t *const pointer =
        reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(
            reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&something)
            + shift);
    std::cout << pointer << " --> " << *pointer << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Don’t try this^^^ at home.  (Or do, just for fun.) On x86_64 this is no big deal. Possible output:

- just built and executed on x86_64:

  ```
  0x7ffc22fd30f8 --> 50607080
  0x7ffc22fd30f9 --> 40506070
  0x7ffc22fd30fa --> 30405060
  0x7ffc22fd30fb --> 20304050
  0x7ffc22fd30fc --> 10203040
  ```
- under `valgrind` on x86_64:

  ```
  0x1fff0007c0 --> 50607080
  0x1fff0007c1 --> 40506070
  0x1fff0007c2 --> 30405060
  0x1fff0007c3 --> 20304050
  0x1fff0007c4 --> 10203040
  ```
- just built and executed on RISC-V (`rv64g`):

  ```
  0x3fffed61c8 --> 50607080
  0x3fffed61c9 --> 40506070
  0x3fffed61ca --> 30405060
  0x3fffed61cb --> 20304050
  0x3fffed61cc --> 10203040
  ```

Do any pointers look odd anywhere?  Pun intended.

A hypothetical overly clever compiler could emulate this^^^ behavior on any platform. However, making the shift (e.g.) a user input can easily rule out that case.

In general, misaligned pointers are discouraged, but [detailed architecture overviews](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo#Alignment) are hard to find. It would be actually great fun to find a platform (architecture + OS + libraries) [where one gets a `SIGBUS`](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-arm-kernel/patch/1491198314-17025-2-git-send-email-kamensky@cisco.com/) for this. Sadly enough I don’t have such a system configured and it won’t give me a `SIGBUS` on my ARM64 phone.

Back to the question:

- *Can* an `int*` pointer be an odd number? **Yes, it can.**
- *Should* an `int*` pointer be odd (or otherwise misaligned)? **No**, because

  - misalignment always comes with a performance penalty, from significant to huge (e.g. trap handlers can be involved to emulate the access in the worst case) and
  - the usual atomicity guarantees may not apply (so e.g. RCU-based algorithms using unaligned pointers may be at risk).

Answer (score 1):

Reaching the question from the other end. There are address space limitations. For example,

> For a 64-bit process on 64-bit Windows, virtual address space is the 128-terabyte range 0x000'00000000 through 0x7FFF'FFFFFFFF

This is not specific to a type, applies equally to `int*` and `char*`

And sure the alignment, which is already answered by other answers.

---

This knowledge on pointer limits is sometimes used to pack extra data into a pointer. This may be useful:

- To conserve memory, say a red-black tree node saves red/black bit in pointer to parent to avoid extra memory for it
- For synchronization algorithms to fit into atomic operations size. For example, a pointer that has a counter to mitigate ABA, has its counter in sparse pointer bits.

Though this is kind of cursed knowledge, especially about address space limits. Limits tend to increase.

(Like there was a limit of 2 GB for 32-bit Windows process, but now with 64-bit Windows it is 4 GB; to make sure old processes that can't work with new range work fine, there's `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag, that defaults to false).