# Would using placement new make the following code valid?

Tags: c++, placement-new

I am building a buffer that will be used in a class and wanted to know if the following is valid according to the C++ standard:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
  alignas(std::int32_t) char A[sizeof(std::int32_t)] = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
  std::int32_t* pA = new (&A) std::int32_t;
  std::cout << *pA << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The buffer has been initialized as a `char` array of 4 bytes.  Would doing a placement new on top of the structure allow me to access the bits underneath as an `int32_t`?  Can I now access the memory space there as 4 `char`s (through the `buffer` object) or as 1 `int32_t` (through `pA`) without any violation to the standard?  If not, is it possible to do some other way?

NOTE: Yes, I am aware of endianness, but in this context, endianness doesn't matter.  That's a different discussion.

Comment: No, now you can't access `A` directly (its lifetime is over) and reading `*pA` reads an uninitialized `int` which is also Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Is there a way to get the compiler to see it as initialized?  There must be as there are buffers that read from files and streams all the time.

Comment: No, you can't. There is no way for to built-in types like this to share the same memory representation and also be simultaneously accessible.

Comment: `memcpy` is the trick.

Comment: Use std::bit_cast for type punning.

Comment: This is *not* how placement `new` is meant to be used. As for accessing multiple bytes as an integer, check [my “answer” here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69808921/8584929), it contains an example of that. Also, you need to carefully consider how things will differ on big-endian and little-endian architectures — is your integer 1 or 2²⁴?

Comment: Do you really want to depend of endianess? `int n = A[0] | A[1] << 8 | A[2] << 16 | A[3] << 24;` (using `std::byte` or `unsigned char`) would be independent of endianess.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of endianness, but in this context, endianness doesn't matter.  That's a different discussion.

Comment: Thx @JaMiT. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Assuming `int` and `int32_t` are the same type for brevity)

In C++20, since `A` is an array of characters, an object of type `int` can be
implicitly created in `A`, so only the following is needed:

```cpp
alignas(int) char A[sizeof(int)] = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
int * pA = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&A[0]);
std::cout << *pA << std::endl;
```

---

The problem with your original `new (&A) int` is that it ends the lifetime of the original `char[sizeof(int)]` object that was initialised, so its value cannot be read. You now have a default-initialized `int`, which is UB to read. Your original code is thus equivalent to:

```
int A;
std::cout << A << std::endl;
```

---

If you can't rely on C++ 20 implicit object creation, you can use type punning methods, which create objects of a different type with the same "bit pattern" (value representation). [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (or a version implemented with `std::memcpy`) can be used:

```
char A[sizeof(int)] = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
int B = std::bit_cast<int>(A);
std::cout << B << std::endl;
```

Or [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to directly copy the value representation:

```cpp
char A[sizeof(int)] = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
int B;
std::memcpy(&B, A, sizeof(int));
std::cout << B << std::endl;
```

---

You *can* use placement new to change the effective type of `A` from `char[sizeof(int)]` to `int`, like so:

```cpp
alignas(int) char A[sizeof(int)] = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
// `A` has effective type `char[sizeof(int)]`; cannot be accessed through `int*`

int * pA = new (&A) int(std::bit_cast<int>(A));
// `A` now has effective type `int`. This line should be optimised to do nothing to `A` at runtime.

std::cout << *pA << std::endl;

// Or using `A` directly
std::cout << *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int*>(A)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Great explanation.  Thx.