# Is the alignment of char in C (and C++) guaranteed to be 1?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Can the `alignof(char)` be anything but 1?

From the [unofficial cppreference.com wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment):

> The weakest (smallest) alignment is the alignment of the types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`, and it is usually 1.

The "usually" seems to imply that it could be something else.

The only thing the C standard stipulates regarding the alignment of `char` is (C11 N1570 6.2.8 paragraph 1):

> The alignment requirement of a complete type can be queried using an `_Alignof` expression. The types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`shall have the weakest alignment requirement.

However, consider the definition of alignment (C11 N1570 6.2.8 paragraph 1, and defined similarly for C++11):

> An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated.

From this, I don't think it makes sense for the alignment of `char` to be anything but `1` due to the requirement that `sizeof(char) ≡ 1`, which implies the distance between adjacent `char` elements can only be `1` byte.

Does this make sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4638295/1774667 -- the array argument is persussive.  Arrays are packed by `size`, and elements must be multiples of `alignof`, thus `alignof(T)` divides `sizeof(T)`.  As `sizeof(char)` is 1, and `alignof(char)` > 0, `alignof(char)` is 1.  Other answers in that question cover the various standard quotes; I might even flag this as a dupe of that question (as its answer implies this one).

Comment: Please provide a reference to the specification or standard of that language C/C++. The standards you cite are for C.

Comment: @Yakk: Sorry, but what means "persussive"?

Comment: If it's implementation defined doesn't that mean it's not guaranteed?

Comment: @olaf persuasive typed on a phone keyboard without spellcheck enabled.

Comment: I think the problem is guaranteeing what adjacent means. For example, defining two global chars one right after the other one does not guarantee that they actually exist in memory next to each other. Also, defining an array of structures containing 3 chars each does guarantee the compiler does not add padding to each structure.

Comment: @Olaf: I had a feeling someone would be unhappy that I wrote it that way. Hopefully the new title is more tolerable?

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks for the link! That is indeed a good argument.

Comment: @Pemdas: arrays are “contiguous” according to the standard, so doesn't that imply they are adjacent?

Comment: someone should submit a DR I guess - it's clear from dozens of possible arguments that it must be `1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. Although this statement is not explicitly specified in the standards, I suppose it can inferred from them:

N1570 [6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4)

> 4 When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has `type char`,
>   `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof)
>   the result is `1`. When applied to an operand that has array type, the
>   result is the total number of bytes in the array.

Taking `char` for example. Say we have an `char charArr[2];`. `sizeof charArr` is guaranteed to be `2`, and `sizeof charArr[0]` = `sizeof charArr[1]` = `1`. This means two adjacent `char` objects take the place of 2 bytes.

Consequently, it can be inferred that "the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a char can be allocated" is at least `1`. Also, the alignment of `char` must be a positive integer, so it can't be any number other than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a language lawyer, but if we look at section 6.5.3.4 paragraph 3 of C:

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
>   (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

To me, this doesn't seem to be a requirement that the size of `char` must be one, just the result of the operand `sizeof` must return 1. Alignment also is not the same thing as size. Alignment is dictated by the ABI, not the C or C++ standards. Of course, it is true that the alignment of `char` is 1 on x86, x86_64 and so on but it's not a hard requirement.

Comment: “The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand” (C11 N1570 6.5.3.4 paragraph 2)