# Extra bytes when declaring a member of a struct as uint32_t

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, structure-packing

I have a problem when using the uint32_t type from the stdint.h library. If I run the following code (on Ubuntu linux 11.10 x86_64, g++ version 4.6.1):

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
typedef struct{
    // api identifier
    uint8_t api_id;

    uint8_t frame_id;
    uint32_t dest_addr_64_h;
    uint32_t dest_addr_64_l;
    uint16_t dest_addr_16;
    uint8_t broadcast_radius;
    uint8_t options;
    // packet fragmentation
    uint16_t order_index;
    uint16_t total_packets;
    uint8_t rf_data[];
} xbee_tx_a;

typedef struct{
    // api identifier
    uint8_t api_id;

    uint8_t frame_id;
    uint16_t dest_addr_64_h;
    uint16_t dest_addr_64_l;
    uint16_t dest_addr_16;
    uint8_t broadcast_radius;
    uint8_t options;
    // packet fragmentation
    uint16_t order_index;
    uint16_t total_packets;
    uint8_t rf_data[];
} xbee_tx_b;


int main(int argc, char**argv){

   xbee_tx_a a;

   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a "<<sizeof (xbee_tx_a)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.api_id "<<sizeof (a.api_id)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.frame_id "<<sizeof (a.frame_id)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_64_h "<<sizeof (a.dest_addr_64_h)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_64_l "<<sizeof (a.dest_addr_64_l)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_16 "<<sizeof (a.dest_addr_16)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.broadcast_radius "<<sizeof (a.broadcast_radius)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.options "<<sizeof (a.options)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.order_index "<<sizeof (a.order_index)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.total_packets "<<sizeof (a.total_packets)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_a.rf_data "<<sizeof (a.rf_data)<<std::endl;

   cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------\n";

   xbee_tx_b b;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b "<<sizeof (xbee_tx_b)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.api_id "<<sizeof (b.api_id)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.frame_id "<<sizeof (b.frame_id)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_64_h "<<sizeof (b.dest_addr_64_h)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_64_l "<<sizeof (b.dest_addr_64_l)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_16 "<<sizeof (b.dest_addr_16)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.broadcast_radius "<<sizeof (b.broadcast_radius)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.options "<<sizeof (b.options)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.order_index "<<sizeof (b.order_index)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.total_packets "<<sizeof (b.total_packets)<<std::endl;
   cout<<"size of xbee_tx_b.rf_data "<<sizeof (b.rf_data)<<std::endl;
}
```

then I get the following output:

```
size of xbee_tx_a 20
size of xbee_tx_a.api_id 1
size of xbee_tx_a.frame_id 1
size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_64_h 4
size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_64_l 4
size of xbee_tx_a.dest_addr_16 2
size of xbee_tx_a.broadcast_radius 1
size of xbee_tx_a.options 1
size of xbee_tx_a.order_index 2
size of xbee_tx_a.total_packets 2
size of xbee_tx_a.rf_data 0
----------------------------------------------------------
size of xbee_tx_b 14
size of xbee_tx_b.api_id 1
size of xbee_tx_b.frame_id 1
size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_64_h 2
size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_64_l 2
size of xbee_tx_b.dest_addr_16 2
size of xbee_tx_b.broadcast_radius 1
size of xbee_tx_b.options 1
size of xbee_tx_b.order_index 2
size of xbee_tx_b.total_packets 2
size of xbee_tx_b.rf_data 0
```

What I'm doing is printing out the total size of a struct and the size of each member of the struct.

In the case of xbee_tx_b the sizes of the members add up to the size of the struct (14)

In the case of xbee_tx_a the sizes of the members add up to 18 bytes... but the size of the struct is 20 bytes!

The only difference between xbee_tx_a and xbee_tx_b is in the type of the dest_addr_64_X members. They are uint32_t in xbee_tx_a and uint16_t in xbee_tx_b. Why is the size of the structure bigger than the sum of the sizes of its members when I use uint32_t? Where do those 2 extra bytes come from?

Thanks!

Comment: The wonders of **Structure Padding**.

Comment: Lookup "padding" and "alignment". Also, since when are we typedefing our structs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs are padded to be an integer multiple of 4 bytes<sup>1</sup> so that they are word-aligned. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding

See also:

- [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)
- [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)
- [Use of struct padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587470/use-of-struct-padding)

---

<sup>1</sup> As [@Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) commented, this isn't *always* true:

> It's not always a multiple of 4 bytes, it varies (slightly) depending on the members. On the other hand, 99% of the time it's a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: It's not always a multiple of 4 bytes, it varies (slightly) depending on the members.  On the other hand, 99% of the time it's a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't know about the 99%.  Most of the structures where I work contains `double`, and so are padded to a multiple of 8.  And of course, if the structure only contains `char` and `char[]`, it probably won't be padded at all.

Comment: @JamesKanze: CTRL-Fs in my project at work: `double`:5(0%), `float`:20(1%), `long`:170(10%), `int`:817(50%),  `short`:140(9%), `char`:495(30%),  Includes comments and literals.  Results _will_ vary.  On the other hand, on 64bit, pointers are 8, so you're probably right.  It's probably closer to 20% than 99%.

Comment: Isn't the general principle that structs are padded to the alignment of the largest member? This applies recursively, and the alignment of a primitive type typically equals its size, or perhaps 8 for `long double`.

Comment: @KerrekSB short answer: no. Amongst other factors, struct padding can depend on the order of the contents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: @MattBall: That's not contradicting what I meant, though. Internally, the struct members are aligned according to their alignment, sure. But the total size of the struct has to be padded to be a multiple of the struct's own alignment, non?

Comment: @MooingDuck It depends a lot on the application.  I've worked a lot on telephone systems in the past, and it was usual for them to not contain a single `double`.  In other applications, however, including the one I'm working on now, `double` is more frequent than `string` or `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of alignment. On your platform uint32_t needs to be 4 byte aligned. In order to achieve that dest_addr_64_h has to have two bytes of padding right in front of it because the position right after the two uint8_t members is a multiple of 2 but not 4.

You can use the macro offsetof() to figure out exactly where members are placed within a struct, to see that this is true.

You can either try to make the compiler pack the members tighter together, or you can rearrange the members so that padding isn't needed.

Comment: Or you can design the code so that it doesn't matter.  There's not much use for a packed structure unless you're deep in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Data types have different alignment requirements based on platform. The extra bytes are used to align one of the members of your structure to a particular size and/or position. IF you need more precise control, you can specify this alignment with [`__attribute__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) or [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare to the compiler to pack the structure

I believe that this will work for GCC

```
struct test
    {
            unsigned char  field1;
            unsigned short field2;
            unsigned long  field3;
    } __attribute__((__packed__));
```

In MS it would be something using the pragma packed

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/14659/

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
struct MyStruct
{
  char b; 
  int a; 
  int array[2];
};
#pragma pack(pop) //back to whatever the previous packing mode was
```

Comment: Yes, but be careful when accessing struct members via pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756811/does-gccs-attribute-packed/7956942#7956942